# Find catch corresponding to a throw in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

When using gotos in c# Visual Studio helps quite well with figuring out the controll flow. Shift-F12 on the label shows me from where the part is reached, and F12 on the goto statment goes to the label.

But I usually use no gotos in my code. In allmost all cases stuctured programming or exceptions seem to be better.

However, when using exceptions the controll flow can be just as confusing as using gotos. Has visual studio equivalent functions for exceptions? e.g. find all throws that one catch could catch, and find the corresponding catch for a throw?

Answer (score 0):

Open your project -> Debug -> Windows -> Exceptions -> Check every kind of exception you are interested about

Comment: That does not solve my problem, as I want to know where where the throw statment in file x, line y jumps to. This only shows me where exceptions that are actually thrown.

Comment: This should tell you

Comment: To me it seems it only stops when exceptions that are thrown duing execution.

Answer (score 0):

c# don't have a goto like Visual Basic 6:

You only have to do a:

```
Try
{
   ....
}
Catch(Exception ex)
{
    String err =  ex.Message;
}
```

You can see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/) as your reference

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this is related to my question. I know how exceptions work, I asked how to use Visual Studio.